# IF-Statement in Field Calculator

Tags: field-calculator, reclassify

I want to use an IF/ELSE-Statement to define a field in the attribute table of my raster.
Therefore I have a field "VALUE". The condition should be: If "VALUE" < 4 ...then use die field "A".....if "VALUE" > 4 then set 0.5.

I was searching for answers but couldn't find a proper one.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Please add more information to this question, so that we can help you out. Details like the software that you are using, what you have tried so far, and where you are currently stuck, will help us give you a better answer.

Answer (score 6):

In Python:

```
def function(field):
    if field>4:
         return "0.5"
    else:
         return "A"
```

And below:

```
function(!choose from Fields!)
```